# typescript addthis.toolbox method

Tags: typescript, addthis

http://www.addthis.com/blog/2013/05/07/a-brief-history-of-using-addthis-dynamically/#.WOIgIvGGMtN

using this method " addthis.toolbox('.addthis_toolbox') " to create toolbox not working for dynamic content on ngOnChanges

public ngOnChanges() {

```
  //console.log(this.shareobject);
 this.sharethishtmlstring = '<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">'
    + '<a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>'
    + '<a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>'
    + '<a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>'
    + '<a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>'
    + '</div>';
  window['addthis'].toolbox('.addthis_toolbox', null, { url: "http:://www.google.com", text: "hello" })
}
```

**window.addthis will throw error for typescript so using window['addthis'] object**

HTML template for component ( using some pipe to render HTML in div block )

```
<div class="do-share-plugin" [innerHTML]="sharethishtmlstring | safeHtml">


</div>
```